# Chrome not showing Saved Passwords

Tags: google-chrome, browser, passwords

My saved passwords are not being populated on sites I visit anymore. I recently downloaded Ubuntu 16 and I seem to have lost my Passwords on my newly installed Google chrome. I checked the following.

1. I have password sync settings turned on in chrome for all my devices (Macbook Air, Samsung Phone, Windows PC).
2. I verified that the google account is the correct one which I have always used to save and sync passwords and other chrome settings.
3. I checked passwords.google.com, making sure it is the correct account and all the saved passwords are gone! I had about 200+ saved passwords previously. So they don't show up on the devices and on my google cloud account anymore!
4. I should also add that along with passwords, the saved addresses are also gone from Chrome settings. The payment methods however still seem to be there.

Of course, I never explicitly deleted or ask to delete passwords from any of my devices.

How should I recover them all in Ubuntu Google Chrome?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just resolved this issue using "Remove Person"

Step 1 
Go to the "Other Person Setting" by clicking your photo on the Google-chrome web browser in the rightmost corner.

step 2
Remove person

step 3
Login again with your Gmail account which has Saved Password details.

step 4 
Turn on Sync

This should sync all the Google Chrome settings as well as your Saved Passwords.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I even uninstalled Chrome. I am on Mac OS Mojave

Comment: This may apply for synced passwords but not for the underlying problem that even locally stored passwords are in some (but not all) cases no longer offered.

Answer (score 25):

Same issue on my Chrome on latest Linux Plasma/KDE

Fixed with:

- goto chrome://flags/
- enable #skip-undecryptable-passwords (*)
- restart chrome

Source:  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1251355#c20

(*) was #clean-undecryptable-passwords

Comment: It worked! Once the passwords are back, the flag can be changed back to the default.

Comment: Worked for me, too. Thanks!

Comment: It's #skip-undecryptable-passwords as of 2022

Comment: confirm #skip-undecryptable-passwords in chrome 110

Comment: Perhaps this option is not available anymore in Chrome 119 ?

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it's because of the disk access control of Chrome.
Chrome saving password requires access to the disk. Some versions of Mac OS like Big Sur & Mojave will block chrome from saving passwords if the user not given chrome disk asscess.

system preference > security & privacy > privacy tab > Fill Disk Access > Unlock Settings and Add Chrome to the access list

Comment: This fixed it for me. After I added chrome, it asked me to restart and I had access.

Comment: Same here! It worked for me for Mac OS 

Answer (score 1):

It is still happening in Chrome 104.0.5112.79. As Augusto correctly noted, it's due to corruption of local Chrome's passwords database (see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1251355#c20 for more details), and chrome://flags/#clean-undecryptable-passwords was removed in recent versions (!?). Basically you're left with 3 options:

- as mentioned in the bug discussion, close Chrome, backup (just in case), then remove `Login Data` db from your problematic profile:

```
cd [PATH_TO_CHROME_PROFILES]/Default
rm "Login Data"
rm "Login Data-journal"
```

Then upon re-opening the browser, passwords should populate.

- Another option is viable if you have a backup of your profile dir, specifically of `Login Data` files. This was my case (experience some crazy data corruption with APFS), and while the backup was 2 weeks old (and I did not want to lose any tabs or history over that period), I recovered only these files from the backup and it helped to re-populate all (including recently saved) passwords from my Google Account.
- Last option is to use the following tool in attempt to salvage your password data: https://github.com/mramendi/chrome_password_grabber/tree/google-fix

Hope Google can fix it soon upstream.

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest solution**
They have not been deleted just google try to keep your passwords safe.

1. Make sure you are login and not paused in chrome
2. Go to https://passwords.google.com/

Answer (score 0):

### For Mac Users only -

```
cd Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default 
rm Login\ Data-journal
rm Login\ Data
```